# Remove duplicate from observable collection bind to listbox

Tags: linq, duplicates, ienumerable, observablecollection

I have an observablecollection list containing FileName, FileImage and FileSize bind to a listbox. The user can select duplicate items and there is a button that should remove the duplicate items in the listbox. My code for remove duplicate button which doesn't work is:

```
    private void BtnRemoveDup_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<MyFiles>();
        IEnumerable<MyFiles> noduplicates = myFilesList.GroupBy(a => new
        {
            a.FileName,
            a.FileImage,
            a.FileSize
        }).Select(g => g.First());

        foreach (var item in noduplicates)
            collection.Add(item);

        myFilesList.Clear() ;

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            myFilesList.Add(item);
        }      
    }
```

Would you please help me to fix the code?

Comment: Does your `MyFiles` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No it doesn't. I thought since I used observablecollection there is no need to use InotifyPropertyChanged.